# Load SVG div to React component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using an NPM package that draws a fretboard using D3 (https://github.com/txels/fretboard)  .It outputs a div with SVG.  I have it working with a normal HTML page but if I try and load it to a React component with code below it gets appended to end of page rather than in div where I have the expression.

Any ideas how I get this generated div in the component div?

```
import React from "react";
import { Fretboard, Tunings } from "fretboards";

const GenerateFret = () => {
  const config = {
    frets: 12, // Number of frets to display
    startFret: 0, // Initial fret
    strings: 6, // Strings
    tuning: Tunings.guitar6.standard, // Tuning: default = Standard Guitar
    fretWidth: 50, // Display width of frets in pixels
    fretHeight: 20, // Display heigh of frets in pixels
    leftHanded: false, // Show mirror image for left handed players
    showTitle: true, // Set the note name as the title, so it will display on hover
    where="#fret"
  };

  const notes =
    "6:e2 6:f2 6:f#2 6:g2 6:g#2 6:a2 6:a#2 6:b2 6:c3 6:c#3 6:d3 6:d#3 6:e3 " +
    "5:a2 5:a#2 5:b2 5:c3 5:c#3 5:d3 5:d#3 5:e3 5:f3 5:f#3 5:g3 5:g#3 5:a3 " +
    "4:d3 4:d#3 4:e3 4:f3 4:f#3 4:g3 4:g#3 4:a3 4:a#3 4:b3 4:c4 4:c#4 4:d4 " +
    "3:g3 3:g#3 3:a3 3:a#3 3:b3 3:c4 3:c#4 3:d4 3:d#4 3:e4 3:f4 3:f#4 3:g4 " +
    "2:b3 2:c4 2:c#4 2:d4 2:d#4 2:e4 2:f4 2:f#4 2:g4 2:g#4 2:a4 2:a#4 2:b4 " +
    "1:e4 1:f4 1:f#4 1:g4 1:g#4 1:a4 1:a#4 1:b4 1:c5 1:c#5 1:d5 1:d#5 1:e5";

  let board = Fretboard(config);
  board.draw(notes);
};

const GameArea = () => {
  return (
    <div id="fret" className="col-8 border border-primary fb-container">
      {GenerateFret()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameArea;
```

There is a config for [where] which changes the D3 selection from body.

I tried adding an ID to the div and then passing in where="#fret" to the config const but this stops any visual from being output.

Comment: does `board.draw(notes)` returns some jsx or it directly manipulates the DOM?

Comment: It manipulates dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually changing the DOM in React components is an example of side effect and therefore should be put inside `useEffect`

Try:

```
const GameArea = () => {
   useEffect(()=>{
       GenerateFret(); // call function inside useEffect
    }, []) // you need to run it only once, so pass empty array

  return (
    <div id="fret" className="col-8 border border-primary fb-container"/>
  );
};
```

This is the whole code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Fretboard, Tunings } from "fretboards";

const GenerateFret = () => {
  const config = {
    frets: 12, // Number of frets to display
    startFret: 0, // Initial fret
    strings: 6, // Strings
    tuning: Tunings.guitar6.standard, // Tuning: default = Standard Guitar
    fretWidth: 50, // Display width of frets in pixels
    fretHeight: 20, // Display heigh of frets in pixels
    leftHanded: false, // Show mirror image for left handed players
    showTitle: true, // Set the note name as the title, so it will display on hover
    where="#fret"
  };

  const notes =
    "6:e2 6:f2 6:f#2 6:g2 6:g#2 6:a2 6:a#2 6:b2 6:c3 6:c#3 6:d3 6:d#3 6:e3 " +
    "5:a2 5:a#2 5:b2 5:c3 5:c#3 5:d3 5:d#3 5:e3 5:f3 5:f#3 5:g3 5:g#3 5:a3 " +
    "4:d3 4:d#3 4:e3 4:f3 4:f#3 4:g3 4:g#3 4:a3 4:a#3 4:b3 4:c4 4:c#4 4:d4 " +
    "3:g3 3:g#3 3:a3 3:a#3 3:b3 3:c4 3:c#4 3:d4 3:d#4 3:e4 3:f4 3:f#4 3:g4 " +
    "2:b3 2:c4 2:c#4 2:d4 2:d#4 2:e4 2:f4 2:f#4 2:g4 2:g#4 2:a4 2:a#4 2:b4 " +
    "1:e4 1:f4 1:f#4 1:g4 1:g#4 1:a4 1:a#4 1:b4 1:c5 1:c#5 1:d5 1:d#5 1:e5";

  let board = Fretboard(config);
  board.draw(notes);
};

const GameArea = () => {
   useEffect(()=>{
       GenerateFret(); // call function inside useEffect
    }, []) // you need to run it only once, so pass empty array

  return (
    <div id="fret" className="col-8 border border-primary fb-container"/>
  );
};
```